# Abnormal website database growth

Tags: commerce

I migrated my site to the production  server about 3 months ago . 2 weeks ago , I noticed that the db was growing too fast(about 40Gb I could not account for) I backed the site , deleted WAMP and restored the site .

Result , slower until within the 2 weeks ,it has grown to a halt . Keeps on "connecting ". 
One other thing( could be related ) the site counter is showing a growth of about 1,000 users anonymous users very hour - this is not possible given the site is either too slow or not working at all outside the LAN

Comment: What tables contain the 40gb of unaccountable data?

Comment: +1 what to what Clive said, and do you have cron running on the live site?

Comment: Yeah, this really needs to be rephrased as a question with specific information about what table is growing. Otherwise there's no way for us to help you. This was tagged drupal-commerce, but you didn't even explain why or how you're using Drupal Commerce. : ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `truncate` `watchdog` table, usually this table growth very quick.( maybe you can first  get a backup of this table then truncate(empty) it)

( maybe trucnate cache tables be useful but If you see table size u will see the watchdog have biggest size )

Answer (score 0):

You have to truncate the table cache_form ..it's the main source of this problem and install the database optimizer module

Comment: I just said that the abnormal growth of a drupal database is often due to the table cache_form,the other tables will be flushed automatically with the cron except this table to prevent any form break